# GetDirectories in C++.net/C++ CLI

Tags: c++-cli, directory-listing

Following the example provided by microsoft for Directory::GetDirectory I came to this piece of code:

```
auto k = System::IO::Directory::GetDirectories(installpath);
auto dir = k->GetEnumerator();
while (dir->MoveNext())
    {
       String^ subdirectory = safe_cast<String^>(dir->Current);
       MessageBox::Show(subdirectory);
    }
```

which should list all directories in installpath, right? Well it doesn't appear to work! (no messagebox) How do I fix this?

note: installpath exists and has subdirectories

Comment: You should single-step through the code in a debugger to see what's it's really doing.

Comment: all i get from the debugger is that k {Length=0}. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, silly me !
Installpath was 1 folder deeper and had nothing in it !
Sorry for the inconvenience!